# Is there any information about UserManager<TUser> which is in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I want to create my own implementation of Microsoft.AspNet.Identity storage data using **Dapper** (this mean, i removed EntityFramework default realization).

I created `MyUserStore`, that implemented `IUserStore` and passed it into `UserManager` like this:

```
    private UserManager<User> _userManager { get; set; }

    public AccountController() : this(new UserManager<User>(new MyUserStore())) {}

    public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager) {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
```

And everything was fine, until i didn't want to add roles (i implemented in `MyUserStore` interface `IUserRoleStore`).

And when i look at `UserManager` signature, i was a little confused, because i dont know how those methods work:

```
[AsyncStateMachine(X)]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public virtual Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(string userId);
[AsyncStateMachine(X)]
[DebuggerStepThrough]
public virtual Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(string userId, string role);
```

I could call them, and could see, how i enter into `MyUserStore`, but in definitely other methods:

```
public Task<IList<string>> GetRolesAsync(User user)
public Task<bool> IsInRoleAsync(User user, string role)
```

So, i get stuck a little, because i can't understand, what should i do with `UserManager` and by the way, with `RoleManager`.

Should i implement my own `UserManager` or i have to use only default realization, and why?

Sry if the question is lame, but there are lot of information about `UserStore`, but nothing about `UserManager, RoleManager` e.t.c.

Answer (score 1):

In choosing to implement your own UserStore, you can implement Roles however you want to store the Roles.

Those methods will only work if you implement IRoleStore

Comment: I know that, but what should i do with `UserManager`?

Comment: You can plug your UserStore to UserManager and it will use it. Can you please rephrase your question? Myabe I am not understanding completely what your question is.